# Wait before Server Side Event kicks for telrik controls

Tags: combobox, telerik

I am using Telerik Combobox with EnableLoadONLoad = True i.e. Every time end user type a letter, server side event kicks in to pull records for that  word. For example, In the dropdown box, if I type America then the system will search for A then AM then AME and so on... and brings results that matches those letters. So, in the case above, the system will ick server side event 7 times. Now the problem is search functionality takes a while (anywhere from 5 - 10 seconds to pull records.. beyond my control :( ) What I want is when end user type something , I want to wait for a second to see if user is still typing. After a second, I want the system to go for search. Hoping that within a second, end user will type whatever they need to. Now I can force the user to type minimum 5 letters and so on but end user can search with a single letter or multiple letters. They don't want to be restricted with no. of letters due to business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify an 'ItemRequestTimeout' in milliseconds of 1000 which will tell the combobox to wait 1 second before firing to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The itemRequestTimeout on their comboboxes is 300 by default which is 3 tenths of a second.  doing what Brian Suggested would work, but I have found that the default is usually enough time before it causes the postback.

Also if you incorporate `MarkFirstMatch="true"` for the ComboBoxes it will automatically go to the item that matches the text if it exists.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx

This should give you some other options as well.

But as far as forcing the user to enter 5 letters before the postback occurs, You would probably need to do onkeyup and onkeydown javascript events to check if they have entered 5 characters and then you could cause the postback.
Or you could use the OnClientkeyPressing property of the Telerik comboboxes to do the check.

```
 function OnClientKeyPressing(comboBox, args)
   {
       if (comboBox.get_text().length > 4) {
         //Do postback here
   }
  }
```

Something like that would do what you want I believe.